# Contador en Recursividad Python

Tags: python, contador

Tengo el típico código de recursividad de las Torres de Hanoi,conozco la fórmula que 2**n - 1 da como resultado el numero de pasos necesarios para realizar completar el juego. Pero necesito un contador implementado dentro de la función recursiva, pero por más que intente colocarlo como parámetro o hacerlo de la forma tradicional como "contador += 1" me da este error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'contador' referenced before assignment"

```
def hanoi(n,inicio,final,auxiliar):      
    contador += 1
    if n == 1:
        print(f"Mover disco {n} de Torre {inicio} a torre {final}")
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,inicio,auxiliar,final)
        print(f"Mover disco {n} de Torre {inicio} a torre {final}")
        hanoi(n-1,auxiliar,final,inicio)
        return


def hanoi_par(n):
    hanoi(n,1,3,2)

def num_mov(n):
    x = 2 ** (n)-1
    return x

print("\n****************TORRES DE HANOI******************")
x = int(input("Ingrese numero de discos: "))
hanoi_par(x)
print(f"\nNúmero de movimientos necesarios: {num_mov(x)}")
```

Comment: `contador` debe ser una variable global **inicializada**. Dentro de la función debes declararla `global contador`. Tal como lo tienes, es una variable local a la función e intentas usarla antes de inicializarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo simple sería declarar `contador` como variable global, pero a costa de perder el control de quién y dónde la pueden alterar:

```py
def hanoi(n,inicio,final,auxiliar):      
    global contador
    contador += 1
    if n == 1:
        print(f"Mover disco {n} de Torre {inicio} a torre {final}")
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,inicio,auxiliar,final)
        print(f"Mover disco {n} de Torre {inicio} a torre {final}")
        hanoi(n-1,auxiliar,final,inicio)
        return

contador = 0
```

Un mejor control sería que la función `hanoi` devolviese el número de movimientos realizados, con lo que puedes llevar mejor las cuentas:

```py
def hanoi(n: int, inicio: int, final: int, auxiliar: int) -> int:

    contador = 0

    if n > 1:
        contador += hanoi(n-1, inicio, auxiliar, final)

    print(f"Mover disco {n} de Torre {inicio} a torre {final}")
    contador += 1

    if n > 1:
        contador += hanoi(n-1, auxiliar, final, inicio)

    return contador


def hanoi_par(n):
    return hanoi(n, 1, 3, 2)


def num_mov(n):
    return 2**n - 1


print("\n****************TORRES DE HANOI******************")
x = int(input("Ingrese numero de discos: "))
total = hanoi_par(x)
print(f"\nNúmero de movimientos necesarios: {num_mov(x)}")
print(f"\nNúmero de movimientos realizados: {total}")
```